# How to control the number of child processes in cassandra server

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to load CSV file to cassandra table using COPY command.By default COPY process is starting with 16 child processes("Using 16 child processes"). I Have given 3 vcpus for the cassandra container.
I feel this 3 vcpus are not sufficient to distribute load to 16 processes because that lot of CPU throttling is happening which is resulting intermittent issue  "NoHostAvailable" during the COPY process and finally job is completing.

I feel that if I limit child processes to half(i.e) 8 then i don't get this intermittent issue - "NoHostAvailable".I know that I can limit this using parameter numprocesses = x while submitting the query, but I want to limit this in the server.

I have tried to set this in the jvm.options file, but it didn't work for me.

```
# For systems with > 8 cores, the default ParallelGCThreads is 5/8 the number of logical cores.
# Otherwise equal to the number of cores when 8 or less.
# Machines with > 10 cores should try setting these to <= full cores.
#-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
# By default, ConcGCThreads is 1/4 of ParallelGCThreads.
# Setting both to the same value can reduce STW durations.
#-XX:ConcGCThreads=8
```

Please let me know how to control numprocesses from the server config.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Run you command by with NUMPROCESSES=8.

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_list ) ]
FROM 'file_name'[ , 'file2_name', ... ] | STDIN
[ WITH option = 'value' [ AND ... ] ]
```

According to the [Apache documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/tools/cqlsh.html),

> NUMPROCESSES The number of child worker processes to create for COPY
>   tasks. Defaults to a max of 4 for COPY FROM and 16 for COPY TO.
>   However, at most (num_cores - 1) processes will be created.

it seems that you can't set this at server level but you can override it at the query level.